# How to Fetch Request With More Attribute in iOS Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, nsfetchrequest

i am Newbie in iOS Development. i make an app that contain CoreData i want to Fetch Core Data in to Distinct Value For that i fetch request like as

```
NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext = [self managedObjectContext];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription  entityForName:@"BookDetail" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

[request setEntity:entity];
[request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
[request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"title"]];
```

it is Only Fetch Distinct Value for `@"title"` Key But i want to Fetch Distinct Value For all My key Like as

```
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"date"]];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"discription"]];
[request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"authorname"]];
```

But it Fetch Only Distict Value for my Last Key Like as Here `@"authorname"` please Give me Solution for it.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at your documentation! `propertiesToFetch` is an Array. You're writing over the array of propertiesToFetch everytime.

You should be doing this:

```
request.propertiesToFetch = @[@"author name",@"date",@"discription"];
```

Comment: Can it Give me Distinct Value Always?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "distinct values"

Comment: i want `"distinct values"`.

Comment: it not give me `distance value`.

Comment: Please update your question to include the data you have and the results you want so I can better understand you @Ramesh

Comment: @DanielGalasko hi Daniel. Lets say I have two columns(username & password) in a table(userdetails) and I have few records like (abc,def),(abc,def),(abc,xyz),(qwe,rty). I need to fetch results which are distinct. so the output here should be (abc,def),(abc,xyz),(qwe,rty). So how can I do this ? Because I think I need to keep a relation like  `select Distinct from userdetails where username = ? & password = ?`

Comment: @ASN I would recommend asking this as a separate question:)

Comment: @DanielGalasko ok . Thanks. Already asked one. Please have a look at this [question link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38652801/deleting-a-record-from-coredata-with-a-where-clause?noredirect=1#comment64724132_38652801)