# Deleting a record from coredata with a where clause

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have an entity(UserDetails) which has two columns (username,password).
for eg:
[image]

from this I'm populating distinct values and displaying them on a table view.

```
     NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription  entityForName:@"UserDetails"
                                                 inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
         NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
         [request setEntity:entity];
         [request setResultType:NSDictionaryResultType];
         [request setReturnsDistinctResults:YES]; 
         [request setPropertiesToFetch:@[@"username",@"password"]]; 
//not sure if this will generate the same output as what I'm thinking of.
    self.users = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil] mutableCopy];
         [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Output expected(from the above code):

- (abc,def)
- (abc,xyz)
- (abc123,def123)
- (s01,s01)

  Now I want to add a delete feature to the table view which should delete from both table and the core data record.

As they are not populated in the same order as that of the coredata model, I want to delete it using something like a `where` clause. So whenever I delete (abc,def) it should delete all the similar records in coredata.

can someone help on how to solve this?

TIA

Comment: You can just find the objects you want to delete from your table view data source, which is `self.users` I believe, and delete them from your `managedObjectContext`.

Comment: @EricQian so I need to do it multiple times? deleting once from the table data source and then from the  managedObjectContext ?

Comment: Why do you have duplicates if you aren't showing them on the UI?

Comment: @Wain I'm just storing username and password every time the user login to the system. Implemented the same in Android(which is easy comparatively) but facing the problem with objective c

Comment: i have to wonder why you're storing username and password in core data?!?

Comment: @Wain : I'm just trying to recreate Manage accounts of gmail to my app. So I'm storing username and password's temporarily in my coredata and whenever the user  click's on another account, it should take the data from db and then process the login activity

Comment: you should only store the username to do that, and if you want auto-login you should be using tokens. And the tokens should be stored in the keychain.

Comment: @Wain Thanks for the info. Will give it a try. But what if with the username is same and password is different(for eg: username: abc, pwd:123 & username:abc, pwd:456, isP= true, the other username has an extra parameter)

Comment: what is the extra parameter? you can store some stuff in core data, but user (identifying) information should not be there (unless encrypted)

Comment: @Wain yeah I'm encrypting them and saving them in the core data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
+(BOOL)deleteDataFromUserDetailsTableWithUserName:(NSString*)strUsername AndPassword :(NSString*)strPassword;
{

    AppDelegate *objApDel = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [objApDel managedObjectContext];

    NSEntityDescription *userEntity=[NSEntityDescription entityForName:kTableName inManagedObjectContext:context];
    NSFetchRequest *fetch=[[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [fetch setEntity:userEntity];
      NSPredicate *p=[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username == %@ AND password=%@", strUsername,strPassword];
    [fetch setPredicate:p];
    //... add sorts if you want them
    NSError *fetchError;
    NSArray *fetchedDetails=[context executeFetchRequest:fetch error:&fetchError];
    for (self.users *details in fetchedProducts) {
        [context deleteObject:details];
    }
    if (fetchError == nil) {
        return YES;
    }
    else
    {
        return NO;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did  and it worked perfectly fine. But I did something like this.  `NSMutableDictionary *allUsers = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil] mutableCopy];
        for(NSManagedObject *theUser in allUsers){
            [managedObjectContext deleteObject:theUser];
        }`

Answer (score 2):

With iOS 9 `NSBatchDeleteRequest` is available. You can use it to delete objects from CoreData similar to `DELETE` in `SQL` using a `WHERE` clause.

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] initWithEntityName:@"UserDetails"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"username==%@ AND password=%@", @"abc", @"def"];
[request setPredicate:predicate];

NSBatchDeleteRequest *deleteRequest = [[NSBatchDeleteRequest alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request];
NSError *error = nil;
[myPersistentStoreCoordinator deleteRequest withContext:myContext error:&error];
```

For prior versions you will have to fetch all objects first and then delete them individually. There is no other way.

Also if you are using `NSFetchedResultsController` you can be notified when those objects get deleted and thus remove them from your `UITableView`.

Comment: Thanks ankur. Will give it a try. My OS is yosemite and X code is 7.2 .

Comment: You don't need to batch delete, you can just iterate the results of the fetch and delete each, as an alternative